# Multiple cursors in Android Studio automatically at every text that matches?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, multiple-cursor

I have been using multiple cursors with `ALT + SHIFT`. Sometimes I need like 20 cursors and I want them at the start of the same portion of text. This is tedious to do every time. Is there a shortcut for this? Like imagine there are 20 instance of the text "foo" in the file then I would like to just select one and ideally it should automatically insert a cursor for all the other instances in the same position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look for the *Select Next Occurrence* option.
On Mac it's used by selecting a word and then `^ G`, on Ubuntu the shortcut is `ALT + J`.

Traverse through every item you wish to change by repeating the key combination.

[image]

Comment: dude, you just saved my life!

Comment: How to undo this option in mac

Comment: You can just press ESC

Comment: For what it's worth, it's `ALT + J` on Windows as well.

Comment: @Savad you can undo this operation on mac using control + shift + G